# How to show items between 51 to 100 only from list on RecyclerView

Tags: android

I want to show items between 51 to 100 from a list containing a size of 200. How can I do that on a custom Adapter. Thank you.

Comment: list.filterIndexed { index, _ -> index in 51..100 }

Comment: Can you please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74948130/how-to-show-items-between-51-to-100-only-from-list-on-recyclerview) the [code you already tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question and tell us what the expected vs the actual result is?

Answer (score 0):

```
val list = (1..200).toList() //creates a list of integers from 1 to 200 
val sublist = list.subList(50, 100) // gets the sublist of items between indices 50 and 100 (inclusive)

for (item in sublist) {
    println(item) // prints the items in the sublist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list.filterIndexed to filter items you want according to index.

Answer (score 0):

Here `getList` is your complete list of `200` items

```
private val originalList = getList()
private val dataList = ArrayList<String>()
private lateinit var customAdapter: CustomAdapter
```

In your `onCreate()`,

```
dataList.addAll(originalList)
customAdapter = CustomAdapter(dataList)
binding.recyclerView.adapter = adapter
```

Now, for your selection (maybe on button click)

```
dataList.clear()
dataList.addAll(originalList.subList(51, 100))
customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```